# Are these equivalent for regular submanifold? Open, image of local diffeomorphism, image of injective local diffeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, submanifold

I was thinking about

1. this: [Is open (topological) smooth embedding equivalent to injective local (homeomorphism) diffeomorphism?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110871/is-open-topological-smooth-embedding-equivalent-to-injective-local-homeomorph)
2. how the image of any local diffeomorphism between smooth $m$-manifolds is open
3. the equivalence of the definitions of smooth regular $k$-submanifold and smooth embedded $k$-submanifold (each of a smooth $m$-manifold)
4. ([not sure about this, but...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009706)) $P$ is an immersed submanifold of the smooth $m$-manifold $M$ if and only if $P$ is the image of an injective immersion into $M$, i.e. there exists smooth $x$-manifold $X$ and smooth injective immersion $F:X \to M$ with image($F$)=$F(X)=P$

   - Edit: Oh right. We can't use inclusion map $i: P \to M$ as the injective immersion because it doesn't even make sense to '$i: P \to M$' is smooth because $P$ is not necessarily a smooth manifold! But anyway, open subsets are regular/embedded submanifolds, sooo...

This leads me to conjecture the equivalence of the following for a smooth $m$-manifold $N$ and a subset $A$ of $N$:

1. $A$ is open in $N$ ([if and only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4116559/open-subset-if-and-only-if-inclusion-is-an-open-map) $\iota: A \to N$ is open map; if and only if $A$ is smooth regular/embedded $k$-submanifold of $N$, with $k=n$)
2. $A$ is the image of a local diffeomorphism into $N$, i.e. there exists smooth $y$-manifold $Y$ and smooth local diffeomorphism $G:Y \to N$ with image($G$)=$G(Y)=A$
3. $A$ is the image of an injective local diffeomorphism into $N$, i.e. there exists smooth $z$-manifold $Z$ and smooth injective immersion $H:Z \to N$ with image($H$)=$H(Z)=A$

Is this true? I'll write my attempts in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 implies 2: Choose $(G,y,Y)=(\iota,n,A)$.

- (and of course: 1 implies 3: Choose $(H,z,Z)=(\iota,n,A)$.)

3 implies 1: same reason as why 2 implies 1: Image of local diffeomorphism is open (in range).

- (and of course: 3 implies 2: Obvious, but anyway: choose $(G,y,Y)=(H,z,Z)$.)

2 implies 3: Here, I'd combine 2 implies 1 and 1 implies 3: Choose $(H,z,Z)=(\iota,n,A)$